# How to handle canceled facebook login dialog in windows 10? (winsdkfb)

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-10-universal

I use this SDK - winsdkfb for my windows UWP app. There I added an option to import photos from facebook. I call the LoginAsync function which SDK has. It opens facebook login dialog in popup.

I want to handle the event when user either closes or clicks cancel on Facebook login dialog popup, and do some actions then. How can I access the dialog window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FBResult response of FBSession.LoginAsync(_fbPermissions) method to check if the FBResult.Succeeded is true or not. If this flag is not true, you can check the FBResult.ErrorInfo to see the reason for failure. When the user cancel the dialog box, the Succeeded flag will be false. This + ErrorInfo object will help you to conclude on the reason for failure.